# Hiding a subview causes delay on segue

Tags: xcode, ipad, segue

I have a sub menu that when the user selects a part of that sub menu, it should segue to another view controller (view flip). in the iOS simulator, there is no noticeable delay, but when i use my iPad 2 (physical), there is a noticeable amount of delay. when segueing back from the child view, showing the hidden view does not cause any delay.

any thoughts?

This is the code.,

> -(void) hideSudeMenu {    //this will hide the sub menu when it transitions from one view controller to another
>   self.leftSliderMenu.hidden = YES; //   [_leftSliderMenu
>   setBounds:CGRectMake(-80, 331, 95, 289)]; }
>
> -(void) showSubMenu {    //this will show the sub menu when it transitions from one view controller back to this view controller
>   self.leftSliderMenu.hidden = NO;    //change //   [_leftSliderMenu
>   setBounds:CGRectMake(-80, 331, 95, 289)];
>       }
>
> -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {    [self showSubMenu]; }
>
> - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {    [self hideSudeMenu]; }

Comment: posting the code that is run when performing the segues or any code that you think might slow down the UI would be helpful.

Comment: Updated my post. I'm just hiding a view. well, changing the spacial property as well but commented that out even before i noticed the delay.